# delete folders older than 1 day

Tags: linux, find, aix

I want to delete all the folders that are older than 1 day with following command:

`find /test -mmin +1440 | xargs rm -rf`

But the output of `find` lists `/test` (and would remove it accordingly).

How can I find only the sub dirs of `/test`? (`-maxdepth` / `-mindepth` not available in AIX)

Comment: you could simply `find /test/*`.

Comment: Which subdirs exactly?  Any under /test but not /test, or max-depth limited?

Comment: Consider an "old" directory containing "new" directories. Should these "new" ones still all be deleted because they're within the "old" directory? Or do we need to avoid deleting an "old" directory that contains "new" directories?

Comment: What do you consider to be the age of a directory? Note that the modification time of a directory file only reflect the last time an entry was added, removed or renamed in it. It is not updated when any of the files (of type regular or directory or other) linked in it are modified. In particular, any change made to subdirectories or their content doesn't affect the modification time of a directory.

Comment: you need to empty folders before you can delete them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @meuh said in his comment, you could use `/test/*` instead of `/test`.
Your command could then look similar to this:

```
find /test/* -type d -mmin +1440 | xargs rm -rf
```

In this case **only the subfolders** of `/test` would be removed.

Comment: Note that `/test/*` omits the hidden directories (in `/test`, not in its subdirs).

Comment: `find`'s output cannot be processed reliably (let alone by `xargs` for which blanks and quotes are also a problem). You should use the `-exec` predicate instead.

Answer (score 7):

POSIXly:

```
find /test/. ! -name . -type d -mtime +0 -exec rm -rf {} \; -prune
```

(we use `-prune` for the directories that we successfully remove so that `find` doesn't complain that they're suddenly gone).

In any case, note that the modification time (as checked by `-mtime` above) of a directory file only reflects the last time an entry was added, removed or renamed in it.

It is not updated when the content of any of the files (of type regular or directory or other) linked in it are modified. In particular, any change made to subdirectories or their content doesn't affect the modification time of a directory.

Note that all of `-mindepth`, `-maxdepth` and `-mmin` are GNU extensions (though they are supported in some other implementations).

The standard equivalent of `find . -maxdepth 1` would be:

```
find . -name . -o -prune
```

For `-mindepth 1`:

```
find . ! -name .
```

For `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1`:

```
find . ! -name . -prune
```

For directories other than `.`, use `find some/dir/. ...` as above.

For other values of depths, you can use `-path`, but note that since it has only been recently added to the standard, some systems (like AIX) still don't have it.

For: `-maxdepth 2`:

```
find . ! -path '*/*/*' -o -prune
```

For: `-mindepth 2`:

```
find . -path '*/*/*'
```

For another dir:

```
find some/dir//. -path '*//*/*/*'
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the -mmin primary is a GNUism that is most likely not supported on AIX as it is a silly expansion compared to what the BSD people and I used as extension in the 1980s already. Given the fact that sfind compiles fine on AIX, I recommend:

```
sfind . -mindepth 1 -type d -mtime +24h -exec rm -rf {} +
```

The code is in schilytools at: https://sourceforge.net/projects/schilytools/files/

Comment: `-mmin` appears to be supported by [AIX 7.1's find](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/find.htm). Here, one can use the POSIX `-mtime +0` though.

Comment: POSIX -mtime -0 has a different meaning than -mtime +24h even though this specific case evaluates the same. The simple POSIX -mtime evaluates true if the time stamp matches within the seconds of a day. The extended time spec evaluates true if there is an exact match, so you may e.g. use -mtime +23h. I still don't understand why a POSIX certified UNIX added a non-POSIX GNUism imstead of a POSIX compliant extension.

Comment: While I also find `-mtime +1440m` makes more sense (though the behaviour is not consistent with that without suffix or with other predicates that take suffices (like -size) (though it's more intuitive)), adding support for a `-mmin` doesn't break POSIX conformance in any way. POSIX explicitely allows implementations adding extensions starting with `-` as it does say that in `find -- x -anything`, `-anything` should not be treated as a file argument (_The first operand that starts with a '-', or is a '!' or a '(', and all subsequent arguments shall be interpreted as an expression..._)

Comment: Given that POSIX does currently not permit -newer +24h, this is a clean POSIX extension. I am sure this will be added to POSIX in the near future (with Issue 8).

Answer (score 0):

```
touch -t 201508260000 dummyfile
find /path/to/files -type f ! -newer dummyfile -delete
```

Timestamp format `yyyyMMddhhmm`

The first line creates a file which was last modified on the 26th August 2015. The second line finds all files in /path/to/file which has a date not newer than the dummyfile, and then deletes them.

If you want to double check it is working correctly, then drop the `-delete` argument and it should just list the files which would be deleted.

[Copied from link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676810/bash-delete-based-on-file-date-stamp)

Answer (score 0):

```
find /test -type d -mtime +1| egrep -v '^/test$'|xargs -I{} rm -rf {}
```

Comment: `-mtime +1` gives you the files that are at least 2 days (48 hours) old. Use `-mtime +0` for files at least 1 day old.